# whats wrong in this javascript code?

Tags: javascript, arrays, function

EDIT : Instruction from codeacademy :

> Define a function search that takes a single argument, name. If the argument passed to the function matches any of the first names in friends, it should log that friend's contact information to the console and return it.

I am learning JavaScript through code academy. I am coding for a simple contact book , which have details of friends and there is asearch function to get the details of the contact/ Here is the code :

```
var friends = {
    bill: {},
    steve: {}
}

friends.bill.firstName = "bill";
friends.bill.lastName = "gates";
friends.bill.number = 587678;
friends.bill.address = ['mes quarters', 'east camp'];

friends.steve.firstName = "steve";
friends.steve.lastName =  "Jobs";
friends.steve.number = 67896986;
friends.steve.address = ["nch colony", "kanjur marg"];

var list = function() {
    for(var friend in friends){
       // console.log(friend);
    }
} 

var search = function(name){
    for(var prop in friends)
    if(name === friends[prop].firstName){
        console.log(friends[prop]);
        return friends[prop];
    }
}

list();
search("bill");
search("steve");
```

This code is not accepted as correct in the codeacademy system. It shows following error :

> Oops, try again! It looks like your search function doesn't return contact information for Steve.

(Codeacademy do not show correct errors many times)

I posted this in the Codeacademy forum and asked for help. I got one reply :

> To answer the question, because your data structure is messed up. Go back into the lesson to get it right:
>
> It's like this:
>
> ```
> var friends = {};
> friends.bill = {
> firstName: "Bill",
> lastName: "Gates",
> number: "(206) 555-5555",
> address: ['One Microsoft Way','Redmond','WA','98052']
> };
> friends.steve = {
> firstName: "Steve",
> lastName: "Jobs",
> number: "(408) 555-5555",
> address: ['1 Infinite Loop','Cupertino','CA','95014']
> };
> ```

Can anyone explain me , what exactly wrong in my code? and what is the correct way? Here is the codeacademy forum link for my question : http://www.codecademy.com/forum_questions/52883d7c548c358401006826#answer-5288c908abf821c7450089fc

Comment: You've got his address and phone number wrong...

Comment: The answer you got on the forum is incorrect. Your data structure is fine. *edit* and your "search" function works fine too. Now perhaps they expected it to return the "address" and not the whole object?

Comment: The code seems OK. Perhaps it checks for the exact data? You know, "Steve" with capital "S", etc?

Comment: @Pointy : I tried all  the permutation and combination. They asked to return contact details. I returned whole object, then tried with address, and then with phone number and many more.

Comment: Question edited. Kindly check.

Comment: The main problem seems to be that the Codeacademy verification system just doesn't work very well.

Comment: Maybe it's case sensitive?  You aren't returning information for *Steve*, you are returning information for *steve*.

Comment: It was the problem with Codeacademy verification system. I changed bill to Bill and steve to Steve in the first name and searched for Bill and Steve instead of bill and steve respectively, the code passed through the system.

Comment: Off-topic: when you use a `for(var prop in obj)` loop, always check [`obj.hasOwnProperty(prop)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty) (unless you want to get properties from object's prototype chain too)

Comment: I would say this isn't a problem with their system...  it's what we mentioned before - it's case sensitive, as is most things when programming.   Just something you should be aware of...  searching for *steve* is NOT the same as searching for *Steve*.

Comment: @Oriol: Please don't confuse beginners with unnecessarily broad constraints. Instead of telling them to "always" do that, tell them when it makes sense, when it doesn't, and the downsides each way.

Comment: @BlueSkies I have linked MDN, which explains it all. I can't explain it well in a comment...

Comment: @Charlie74 : The name is chose by me. I used "steve" and "bill" everywhere. So why the system expected for "Steve" and "Bill" is strange. Kindly read the code academy instruction I posted on top of the question.

Comment: @narayanpatra **ACTUALLY**, that is not correct.   I checked the site, and it specifically **REQUIRES** that you use `Bill` and `Steve` in the examples.   As a matter of fact, this quote comes directly from your lesson -- `Make sure bill's first name is "Bill" and steve's first name is "Steve" (again, note the capitalization).`

Comment: @Charlie74 : Than you did not check the site properly. I copied and pasted the instructions on top of my question. Kindly check, you won't find any 'bill' or "Bill".

Comment: @narayanpatra You are only correct in that the requirement is not listed for that specific step.  Earlier in your lesson, 12.3 and 12.4 specifically, you are required to use *bill* and *steve*.   Your statement that you chose to use bill and steve is incorrect (it's actually a lie).   You were stuck on 12.7, because you did not follow the directions earlier in the lesson and make sure the first names were capitalized.   So in the future, make sure you read and follow the directions when taking a lesson.

Answer (score 2):

Is this just for passing the Codeacademy test, or for working out a proper contact book? If it's the latter case, use a class:

### For an app

```js
"use strict";
var Contact = function(fName, lName, number, address) {
  this.firstName = fName;
  this.lastName = lName;
  this.number = number;
  this.address = address;
};
var contacts = [];
```

And then, to add contacts, use:

```js
function addContact(fn, ln, nm, ad) {
  contacts.push(new Contact(fn, ln, nm, ad));
}

addContact("Bill", "Gates", "(206) 555-5555", ['One Microsoft Way','Redmond','WA','98052']);
```

And to search:

```js
function searchContact(query) {
  for(var x in contacts) {
    if(contacts[x].firstName == query) {
      return contacts[x];
    }
    else
      return false;
  }
}
```

### For the test

However, if you mean to pass this test only, my guess is that you should mimic the code from the exercise. The validator script probably checks if your names `== "Bill"` and `"Steve"` - meaning the strings you used, `"bill"` and `"steve"` would never pass the test due to case sensitivity.

The test is supposed to help you learn programming, so try to study the code until you find the significant difference from what you've done and what works! Best of luck.

Comment: -1: `==` is case sensitive, like `===`. E.g. `'bill' != 'Bill'`

Comment: Fixed - either way, what I said still holds; `"bill"` is different from `"Bill"` in the site's exercise checker. Fixed the `==` false statement, though. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
var friends= {};
friends.bill={
    firstName:"Bill",
    lastName:"Gates",
    number:"9966334418",
    address: ['One Microsoft Way','Redmond','WA','98052']
    };

friends.steve={
    firstName:"Steve",
    lastName:"Jobs",
    number:"9966224418",
    address:['banglore',]
    };
   var list = function(obj) {
  for(var prop in obj) {
    console.log(prop);
  }
};

var search = function(name) {
  for(var prop in friends) {
    if(friends[prop].firstName === name) {
      console.log(friends[prop]);
      return friends[prop];

    }
  }
};

list(friends);
search("Steve");
```

Comment: good answers provide explanation, not just some code. Also, is there anything you find insufficient in the other answer that motivated you to post your own?

Answer (score 1):

Same thing happens to me, though I suspect it's a bug on CodeAcademy's end, owing to the fact that after being able to display Steve's contact information, I got this error: "Oops, try again. It looks like your search function doesn't return contact information for Bill".